# ListView - getView is called too much times

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I know there are few questions regarding this issue of 'getView called few times' but my problem is little different.

I have a custom listView with custom row ( used a row_layout.xml).
It generally works well. At the beginning I had a problem with multiple calls to getView and it was fixed by using one of the methods I saw here in stackoverflow. ( using the 'usedPositions' array).

now, I see in the logs this scenario: getView pos 0, getView pos 1, getView pos 0 , getView pos 1.
This caused my rows to be doubled. It happens only when I call a new activity that covers the current activity and then close that activity. ( for example, open the camera activity and then close it).

I will show my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.context, "getView " + position, 1000);
    toast.show();
    String pos = Integer.toString(position);
    if (!usedPositions.contains(pos)) { 

        CardHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new CardHolder();
            //holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtCouponTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.txtBusinessName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtBusinessName);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (CardHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Card card = data.get(position);
        holder.txtCouponTitle.setText(card.couponTitle);
        holder.txtBusinessName.setText(card.businessName);
        //holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(card.icon);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.imagesTable); 
        for (int r=1; r<=1; r++){ 
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this.context); 
            for (int c=1; c<=10; c++){ 
                ImageView im = new ImageView (this.context); 
                im.setImageDrawable(this.context.getResources().getDrawable(c<= card.numberOfStamps ? R.drawable.stamp_red :R.drawable.stamp_grey)); 
                im.setPadding(6, 0, 0, 0); //padding in each image if needed 
                //add here on click event etc for each image... 
                //... 
                tr.addView(im, 40,40);  
            } 
            table.addView(tr); 
        } 

        // Your code to fill the imageView object content 
        usedPositions.add(pos); // holds the used position 
    } 
    else
        usedPositions.remove(pos);

    return row;
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom listview adapter getView method being called multiple times, and in no coherent order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2639159/593709) android engineer [RomainGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy)

> This is not an issue, there is absolutely no guarantee on the order in
>   which getView() will be called nor how many times.

So the best you can handle is [re-using the existing views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2872996/593709) (row layouts) properly.

[Here is another](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) good post.

Comment: can you suggest how to reuse it?

Comment: I get stackoverflow error in listview and according to @LalitPoptani recursive call to a method generates this exception. I am using Android 2.3. Please share your views.