# Android ListView with Switch onCheckedListener weird

Tags: android, listview, switch-statement

I am fairly new to android development and started a little app project. Now I have a problem I can't seem to be able to solve alone and found no solution in searching. So I hope you'll have an advice for me :)

I have a ListView with a template like this:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/trackingSwitch"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="#545454"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:text="Time"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1" />
 </GridLayout>
```

It works quite well, giving me a Switch Button and two Text fields right to it. Now I want to fill it with my object data, therefore I extend an ArrayAdapter and have this in getView():

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    final AniTracking aniTracking = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (view == null) {
        view =      LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tracking_list, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    Switch swActive = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.trackingSwitch);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    swActive.setChecked(aniTracking.isActive());
    tvName.setText(aniTracking.getName());
    tvTime.setText(aniTracking.getCurrentTrackingTime());


    // attach listener to switch
    swActive.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean newStatus) {
            // switch set to active? start new AniTrackingPart
            if (newStatus == true) {
                AniTrackingPart aniTrackingPart = new AniTrackingPart();
                aniTrackingPart.setStartTime(new DateTime());
                AniTrackingManager.getInstance(getContext()).addAniTrackingPart(aniTracking, aniTrackingPart);
            }
            // set to inactive -> close current AniTrackingPart
            else {
                AniTrackingManager.getInstance(getContext()).closeActiveTrackingPart(aniTracking);
            }
        }
    });

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return view;
}
```

My problem is the onCheckedChange Listener. When I append it the Switches behave weird, giving every item the state of true. I noticed the getView() method is called more than once for a position, do I need to care about that on my own?
I also have the feeling the listener might be triggered for position1 when I populate data for position2 (swActive.setChecked(aniTracking.isActive())), is that possible?

I am thankful for every help, this makes my progress stop for some days now.

Have a nice day,
Ani

Edit to clarify not being a duplicate question: The problem would also exists if the getView() wouldn't be called multiple times. As its being called for each item in the ListView the calls for position > 1 would already trigger my listener and give me false results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView - getView is called too much times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157523/listview-getview-is-called-too-much-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is finding out why your `notifyDataSetChanged` is being called so many times. That will trigger getView for all visible views.

Your second problem, `setChecked` will trigger your `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

You can avoid that by using `setOnClickListener` instead:

```
    switch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (switch.isChecked()) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

to make sure it's only called when it's touched, not by any ui-induced change.

(you'll also need to change your switch to `final Switch`)

Comment: Thanks, the OnClickListener instead of the OnCheckedChangeListener made it all work :)

Comment: Bear in mind, that swiping the switch (instead of clicking) won't trigger this listener.