# Xamarin android Save data from list view to database by webservice

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have button in every item in list view when i try save last item no problem but when i try save another item it save data many times

this is my code

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

```
    {

        var item = trans[position];

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new

            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.trans_layout, null);

   view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.supply_amount_txt).Text = item.amount1;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.demand_amount_txt).Text = item.amount2;
        //view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text3).Text = item.client_code;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.supply_cur_txt).Text = item.cur1;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.demadn_cur_txt).Text = item.cur2;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.rate_txt).Text = item.rate;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ID_txt).Text = item.tran_id;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.user_name_txt).Text = item.username;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tran_date_time_txt).Text = item.tran_date ;
        accept_btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);        
        amo2 = Convert.ToDecimal(item.amount2);
        cu2 = item.cur2;
        amo1 = Convert.ToDecimal(item.amount1);
        cu1 = item.cur1;
        rat = Convert.ToDecimal(item.rate);
        tr_id = Convert.ToInt32(item.tran_id);
        cl_code = item.client_code;
           accept_btn.Click +=delegate {
               myWS.ChekTranIDAsync(Convert.ToInt32(item.tran_id));
               XTran = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToInt32(item.tran_id));
               myWS.ChekTranIDCompleted += MyWS_ChekTranIDCompleted;

           };
 


        return view;
      
    }


private void MyWS_ChekTranIDCompleted(object sender, myWS.ChekTranIDCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //myWS.accept_tranAsync("123", Convert.ToDecimal(item.amount2), item.cur2, Convert.ToDecimal(item.amount1), item.cur1, Convert.ToDecimal(item.rate), "ابو ليلى", Convert.ToInt32(item.tran_id), item.client_code);
        myWS.accept_tranAsync("123", amo2, cu2, amo1, cu2, rat, "xxx", XTran, cl_code);
        myWS.accept_tranCompleted += MyWS_accept_tranCompleted;


    }
```

Comment: We can not make sure there is absolutely no guarantee on the order in which getView() will be called nor how many times. It would be better to reuse the the old view.

Comment: can you explain more please?!

Comment: What do you want to know more about it?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thanks for your help.... you said "It would be better to reuse the the old view" how I can do it?!

Comment: The old view is the convertView  which reused. You could refer to the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2873471

Answer (score 0):

```
accept_btn.Click +=delegate
```

This code is executed multiple times as items are recycled for visual display and GetView gets run multiple times for the same view holder. So you need to unsubscribe first.

Comment: Can you Explain more  please?!